# Count Group By and Separate If Included in Both Group

Tags: mysql, sql, gql, legacy-database

Not sure if this question is duplicated yet or not.

I have a simplified table below

| User | Interest |
| --- | --- |
| Jason | Art |
| Jason | Sport |
| Sam | Sport |
| Sam | Art |
| Steve | Sport |
| Desmond | Sport |
| Tania | Art |

Here's the result that I want to achieve

| Interest | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Art | 2 |
| Sport | 2 |
| Both | 2 |

I Managed to make a subquery to achieve the value for the `Both` data by this query

```
SELECT COUNT(USER) FROM (
SELECT User, COUNT(DISTINCT Interest) as interest_type FROM table WHERE interest_type = 2)
```

But for the user that are exclusively have `Interest` in `Art` and in `Sport` it's not separated.

Comment: what database is being used? "sql" is NOT enough to identify which dialeect of that language to use

Comment: Well, I'm actually using Big Query and this is just a simplified sample of the data that I have. I'll add some tags for that, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT User,
           CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Interest = 'Art' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
                     COUNT(CASE WHEN Interest = 'Sport' THEN 1 END) > 0
                THEN 'Both'
                WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Interest = 'Art' THEN 1 END) > 0
                THEN 'Art'
                ELSE 'Sport' END AS Interest
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY User
)

SELECT Interest, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY Interest;
```

On MySQL or BigQuery, we can shorten the above to:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT User,
           CASE WHEN SUM(Interest = 'Art') > 0 AND SUM (Interest = 'Sport') > 0
                THEN 'Both'
                WHEN SUM(Interest = 'Art') > 0
                THEN 'Art'
                ELSE 'Sport' END AS Interest
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY User
)

SELECT Interest, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY Interest;
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. Picking this as the right answer just because it's faster by a few milliseconds than @PaulMaxwell answer! (both have the same billable bytes on bigquery)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database supports the `over()` clause:

```
select
      case when num_interests = 1 then interest else 'both' end as interest
    , count(distinct user) as "Count"
from (
    select
      interest
    , user
    , count(*) over(partition by user) as num_interests
    from yourTable
    ) d
group by
      case when num_interests = 1 then interest else 'both' end
```

Comment: BigQuery does support `over()` clause :D and this works! But, picking @TimBiegeleisen for the right one just because it's faster by a few milliseconds. (both have the same billable bytes on BQ)